# Does Mathematica 12 support GT 730 CUDA?

Tags: neural-networks, gpu

I am getting the following error when I set the target device as GPU:

> NetTrain::trgdevegpu: TargetDevice -> GPU could not be used; a
>   supported NVIDIA GPU was not found. If you are using an external GPU,
>   ensure it is attached and recognized by your OS; restarting your
>   system may help. Additionally, check that you are using the latest
>   drivers from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx.

Does Mathematica 12 support GT 730 CUDA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Details sections of the documentation page `ref/TargetDevice`, there's a table that might help:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @M.R

[image: GT 730 Compute capability]

Then, GT 730 is not supported.

Compute capability of CUA GPUs:https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Compute capability requirement for mathematica:https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetDevice.html